# unable to pass variables to oracle sql file (as part of a schema name) that is being called from a shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, variables, scripting

getting an error on trying to pass a variable as a schema name for an sql  file and I need a way to get this done.

I have noticed I do not get any error on passing a variable in a where clause of an sql statement.

I have tried with the below ways:
1)
Shell script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
b=`sqlplus -silent $dbconnect @abc.sql prd01`
```

SQL script:

```sql
Set Heading off
Set term off
Spool xyz.csv
Select * from pkk$'&1'_02.tab1
Where 
Col = 'S';
```

```
ERROR- 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

2. 

Shell script 1:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
b=`sqlplus -silent $dbconnect @abc.sql prd01`
```

SQL script:

```sql
Set Heading off
Set term off
Spool xyz.csv
Select * from pkk$"&1"_02.tab1
Where 
Col = 'S';
```

```
ERROR- 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

3. 

Shell script 1:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
b=`sqlplus -silent $dbconnect @abc.sql prd01`
```

SQL script:

```sql
Set Heading off
Set term off
Spool xyz.csv
Select * from pkk$&1_02.tab1
Where 
Col = 'S';
```

No error:
but waiting prompt to pass a variable

No error on passing the variable in the where clause
Shell script 1:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
b=`sqlplus -silent $dbconnect @abc.sql prd01`
```

SQL script:

```sql
Set Heading off
Set term off
Spool xyz.csv
Select * from pkk$prd01_02.tab1
Where 
Col = '&1';
```

No error

Comment: This isn't just a shell problem -- you can't use bind variables in table names in other SQL interfaces either (Python's DB-API, Java's JDBC, etc) without the same class of fix you'd need to use here. (One class of approaches is SQL-specific and basically comes down to `eval`, and the other class of approach involves editing the query before sqlplus sees it; from a security perspective, neither approach is great unless care is taken in implementation to audit the value being substituted to ensure that it can't have unwanted effects).

Comment: ...so I would generally suggest updating the tagging here to identify it as a SQL problem, to invite solutions from folks who know SQL. Right now, you'll only get proposed solutions from folks who know shell -- so they'll all be of the "edit the query before it reaches sqlplus" variety.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In Oracle, the `&` syntax is for a substitution variable and before parsing the query the substitution variables will be substituted for the values as if you had done a find-replace on the source code. `:` is for a bind variable and that is not what is being used here.

Comment: For general reference, here are some substitution variables examples: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/sql*plus-substitution-variables-define-variables-and-parameters-in-sql-queries#9

Answer (score 4):

In sqlplus, you need to use a '.' if the variable name is followed by something, in your case write your sql like this:

```
Select * from pkk$&1._02.tab1
Where 
Col = 'S';
```

And, if you tried your script by logging in sqlplus and running it interactively, you would have seen your error.

Comment: This behaviour is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#d12359e318).